# Passing python list to javascript function

Tags: javascript, python, json

I want to pass python list as an argument to a JS function. No matter what I try, it gives me "unterminated string literal". I don't know whats going wrong.

My python code is (.py file):

```
request.filter+= '<input type="checkbox" name="select_all" onclick=selectAll(%s) />Select All <br/>' %(str(list))
```

My .pt file has javascript function, `selectAll(type)`.

I tried to convert list to json format by using `simplejson.JSONEncoder().encode(list)` which is also not helping.

Kindly help ...

Thanks ,
Shreya

Comment: Will you please give more information and reformat your question.

Comment: Is the JSON encoder reporting any errors?

Comment: do you have a newline after "checkbox" in you actual Python code? Use `json.dumps(lst)` to produce json text. Make onclick value a valid html attribute (surround it with quotes, escape `"` -> `&quot;`, etc) or better yet set the event handler inside a `<script>` tag. You might want to separate data generation and its rendering as html (you could use javascript or templates to produce html).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
import simplejson
request.filter+= '''<input type="checkbox" name="select_all" onclick='selectAll(%s)' />Select All <br/>''' % simplejson.dumps(list)
```